# Peut-on parler d'un cas de redondance dans la locution « durée de temps » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire

*Quelques exemples dans lesquels se trouve la locution en question*

- (1724) Car c'est de toutes-ces circonstances que dépend la durée de temps que le ressort emploie à se comprimer, 6c à se relever. (Histoire de l'Académie royale des sciences année 1699 Académie des sciences, ‎Fontenelle)
- (1793) L'année solaire est la durée de temps que le soleil paroit employer à parcourir dans l'écliptique les douze signes du zodiaque (Encyclopédie méthodique ou par ordre de matières: ..., Gaspard Monge)

Chose bizarre, la locution disparait quasiment des livres au XIXe siècle mais persiste jusqu'à nos jours dans d'autres publications.

- Toute personne qui accèdera à votre photo pourra la voir pendant la durée de temps que vous avez sélectionnée.
- Et ne peut pas travailler plus de 35 heures par semaine. La différence avec les mineurs de moins de 16 ans est la durée de temps de travail ...

Le mot « durée » selon le [TLFi (A. 1.)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dur%C3%A9e) signifie « continuité indéfinie du temps, du devenir » et selon cette même entrée du TLFi qui défini ce terme, son synonyme principal est « temps ». On nous dit que cette définition se conçoit  « En parlant du temps absolu, indéfini, non mesuré, et p. oppos. à la dimension spatiale ». Il est donc raisonnable de conclure en se fondant sur les exemples ci-dessus que dans la locution « durée de temps », « durée » n'a pas cette signification. De plus le sens « 2 » restant sous « A » n'est de toute évidence pas applicable. Comme il en est de même pour les sens dans « C » cela nous laisse pour seul choix l'un de ceux sous « B ».
Dans cette série de sens c'est « 3. » qui convient.

> 3. Intervalle de temps déterminé pendant lequel se produit une action, un état, un phénomène, du début à sa fin; ou qui sépare deux événements.

Il n'y a aucune difficulté à admettre le temps comme étant un phénomène et alors la locution se trouve être équivalente à « intervalle de temps dans lequel se produit le temps » ou encore « intervalle de temps de temps », ce qui serait d'une redondance flagrante.

1/ Est-ce que cette déduction apparait être correcte ?
2/ Comment justifier la disparition de la locutions dans les livres depuis le XIXe  siècle ?
3/ Si la déduction est correcte est-ce que la redondance se trouverait tant soit peu justifié et/ou explicable d'une façon quelconque ?
4/ Sinon qu'est-ce qui pourrait l'expliquer et justifier que l'usage de « durée de temps » soit préservé même dans une langue moins formelle ?

PRÉCISIONS POUR INFIRMER QUE CONJNCTION ET PRONOM À LA SUITE NULLIFIENT L'EXISTENCE D'UNE LOCUTION

se faire que dans une durée de temps divisible. (1822)
, ainsi que celle d'une durée de temps. (1990)
Long-temps désigne seulement une certaine mesure, une durée de temps, d'existence, d'action : (1818)
le photon passe d'une unité d'espace A à l'unité B – est la durée de temps la plus petite possible. (2012)
« ce moment actuel étant l'essence même du présent, répand sa présence sur toute cette durée de temps, même la plus longue, qui le renferme dans ses limites (!). (1840)
 si cette parole marque une durée de temps plus courte que celle de cette vie (1696)
 la roue fait, par conséquent, un tour par 45 secondes, et 8o par heure, et peut donner une durée de temps de ... (1825)
 il était néanmoins nécessaire de l'insérer dans le code, à cause de la longue durée de temps pendant le— quel il recevra son exécution. (1836)
Fixer au contraire une durée de temps, c'est se faire prophète, c'est dire : je paierai telle marchandise à tel prix, (1824)
Si une certaine épaisseur de sédiments représente une certaine durée de temps (l'épaisseur […]), inversement, les périodes de non-dépôt (1983)

Cela n'est qu'un échantillon.

Answer (score 1):

"Durée de temps" n'est pas une redondance, c'est une absurdité. "Quelle est la durée de ce film ?" "Combien de temps dure la projection".

Answer (score 0):

Mon **opinion** est que, dans les exemples proposés dans l'OP (et d'autres que j'ai aussi pu trouver par ailleurs) il ne faut pas isoler *durée de temps* des autres mots constituant la phrase.

*durée de [ **temps que** xyzt emploie* ] Le relatif *que* est mis pour le temps et seulement le temps.

On pourrait trouver de façon similaire un participe passé :

*durée de [ **temps employé** par xyzt ]* (notez l'accord du pp)
De fait, ce n'est pas la durée que l'on emploie mais bien le temps.

C'est le temps que l'on consomme ou passe, pas la durée. Une durée, cela ne se consomme ni se passe.

Je parlerais d'ailleurs, et pour la même raison de l'*intensité de courant induit* (et non pas induite) ou de l'intensité de courant qui passe dans la bobine.

Il n'y a donc aucune redondance. Il y a d'une part [ une durée ] et, parce qu'il s'agit d'une durée de  [ quelque chose ], d'autre part une description du quelque chose.

Il en irait identiquement pour la *durée de [temps de travail]*

Je rajouterais bien **syntaxe** dans les tags de l'OP.

---

<sup>NDaCOSwt : En physique contemporaine on parlerait plutôt de ***quantité*** de temps mais il se trouve que la notion de *quantité* passe mal dans l'usuel pour ce qui est du temps.</sup>

Comment: "et d'autres que j'ai aussi pu trouver par ailleurs" ? Pourquoi pas "et d'autres que j'ai aussi pu**S** trouver par ailleurs" ?

Comment: @Dimitris Votre cas précis manque dans ce qui suit, je crois, mais c'est un début : https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/je-lui-ai-donne-tous-les-conseils-que-j-ai-pu-ou-que-j-ai-pus/

Comment: @Dimitris La règle :  «  (LBU  951 14e ed.)  Participe passé suivi d'un infinitif.
a) Le participe passé conjugué avec avoir et suivi d'un infinitif (avec
ou sans préposition) s'accorde avec le complément d'objet direct
(voir N. B. ci-dessous) qui précède quand l'être ou l'objet désignés par ce complément font l'action exprimée par l'infinitif. ». « autres » ne fait pas l'action de trouver.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais étudié le Grec mais il me semble avoir lu que le grec  Χρόνος voulait dire « durée de temps », quelque chose à creuser de ce côté ? Pour parodier certains je dirais bien que je ne comprends pas pourquoi cette réponse a été moinssoyée. Pour parodier encore plus il parait que certaines voies (voix) sont impénétrables...